# Incorrect new kernel version installed after apt-get upgrade, how do I downgrade it?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, updates, downgrade

On January 10, 2021, I performed an `apt-get upgrade`, then rebooted. This broke all of my sound devices. [After some research](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes), it seems that the version of ubuntu I'm running (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS) is supposed to be running on kernal version 5.4. However, when I run `uname -a`, It says I'm running a newer version, 5.8.

I suspect my sound issues are due to the incorrect kernel being installed. How can I downgrade my kernel to 5.4 and make sure the incorrect kernel version will not be installed again?

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux gamebuster-Area-51-X58 5.8.0-34-generic #37~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 14:53:00 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

History.log:

```
Start-Date: 2021-01-04  06:11:18
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: gamebuster (1000)
Upgrade: whoopsie:amd64 (0.2.69ubuntu0.1, 0.2.69ubuntu0.2), gnome-system-monitor:amd64 (3.36.0-1, 3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libwhoopsie0:amd64 (0.2.69ubuntu0.1, 0.2.69ubuntu0.2), libinput-bin:amd64 (1.15.5-1ubuntu0.1, 1.15.5-1ubuntu0.2), libinput10:amd64 (1.15.5-1ubuntu0.1, 1.15.5-1ubuntu0.2)
End-Date: 2021-01-04  06:11:25

Start-Date: 2021-01-05  06:30:27
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: python-apt-common:amd64 (2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.3)
End-Date: 2021-01-05  06:30:28

Start-Date: 2021-01-05  06:30:30
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libproxy1v5:amd64 (0.4.15-10ubuntu1.1, 0.4.15-10ubuntu1.2), libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:amd64 (0.4.15-10ubuntu1.1, 0.4.15-10ubuntu1.2), libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager:amd64 (0.4.15-10ubuntu1.1, 0.4.15-10ubuntu1.2)
End-Date: 2021-01-05  06:30:31

Start-Date: 2021-01-05  06:30:34
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: python3-apt:amd64 (2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.3)
End-Date: 2021-01-05  06:30:34

Start-Date: 2021-01-05  06:30:37
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libproxy-tools:amd64 (0.4.15-10ubuntu1.1, 0.4.15-10ubuntu1.2)
End-Date: 2021-01-05  06:30:42

Start-Date: 2021-01-05  06:30:45
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64, 5.4.0-59.65)
End-Date: 2021-01-05  06:30:45

Start-Date: 2021-01-05  06:30:48
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-modules-5.4.0-59-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-59.65, automatic), linux-image-5.4.0-59-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-59.65, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-59-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-59.65, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.58.61, 5.4.0.59.62)
End-Date: 2021-01-05  06:31:16

Start-Date: 2021-01-05  06:31:19
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (5.4.0.58.61, 5.4.0.59.62)
End-Date: 2021-01-05  06:31:19

Start-Date: 2021-01-05  06:31:22
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-headers-5.4.0-59:amd64 (5.4.0-59.65, automatic), linux-headers-5.4.0-59-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-59.65, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.58.61, 5.4.0.59.62)
End-Date: 2021-01-05  06:31:44

Start-Date: 2021-01-06  06:12:54
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-modules-nvidia-455-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-56.62), linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-56.62), linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-56.62), linux-modules-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-56.62)
End-Date: 2021-01-06  06:13:08

Start-Date: 2021-01-06  06:13:13
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-56.62)
End-Date: 2021-01-06  06:13:14

Start-Date: 2021-01-06  06:13:19
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.4.0-56:amd64 (5.4.0-56.62)
End-Date: 2021-01-06  06:13:20

Start-Date: 2021-01-06  06:13:25
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: p11-kit-modules:amd64 (0.23.20-1build1, 0.23.20-1ubuntu0.1), libp11-kit0:amd64 (0.23.20-1build1, 0.23.20-1ubuntu0.1), libp11-kit0:i386 (0.23.20-1build1, 0.23.20-1ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-06  06:13:26

Start-Date: 2021-01-06  06:13:31
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox-locale-en:amd64 (84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 84.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-06  06:13:31

Start-Date: 2021-01-06  06:13:36
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libopenexr24:amd64 (2.3.0-6ubuntu0.2, 2.3.0-6ubuntu0.3)
End-Date: 2021-01-06  06:13:36

Start-Date: 2021-01-06  06:13:41
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox:amd64 (84.0+build3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 84.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-06  06:13:50

Start-Date: 2021-01-06  06:13:55
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: p11-kit:amd64 (0.23.20-1build1, 0.23.20-1ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-06  06:14:04

Start-Date: 2021-01-07  06:40:53
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libwavpack1:amd64 (5.2.0-1, 5.2.0-1ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-07  06:40:54

Start-Date: 2021-01-08  05:08:20
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.1206'
Install: libxcb-xfixes0:i386 (1.14-2, automatic), linux-modules-5.8.0-34-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2, automatic), libllvm11:amd64 (1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1, automatic), libllvm11:i386 (1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-nvidia-455-5.8.0-34-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2, automatic), linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2, automatic)
Upgrade: libnvidia-compute-455:amd64 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-compute-455:i386 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libegl1:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-encode-455:amd64 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-encode-455:i386 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-kernel-common-455:amd64 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-455:amd64 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-gl-455:amd64 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-gl-455:i386 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgles-dev:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgl1:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgl1:i386 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libasound2-data:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.2, 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.3), libnvidia-fbc1-455:amd64 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-fbc1-455:i386 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-decode-455:amd64 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-decode-455:i386 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libglx-dev:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libopengl0:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-cfg1-455:amd64 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgles1:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgles2:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-utils-455:amd64 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libegl-dev:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libglvnd-dev:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-compute-utils-455:amd64 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-ifr1-455:amd64 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-ifr1-455:i386 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-driver-455:amd64 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libglx0:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libglx0:i386 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), nautilus-sendto:amd64 (3.8.6-3, 3.8.6-3ubuntu0.20.04.1), linux-modules-nvidia-455-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64, 5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2), libasound2:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.2, 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.3), libgl-dev:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-common-455:amd64 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), linux-firmware:amd64 (1.187.6, 1.187.7), libopengl-dev:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-extra-455:amd64 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libatopology2:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.2, 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.3), nvidia-kernel-source-455:amd64 (455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libglvnd0:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1), libglvnd0:i386 (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-08  05:09:36

Start-Date: 2021-01-08  06:27:01
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-60.67, automatic), linux-headers-5.4.0-60:amd64 (5.4.0-60.67, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.59.62, 5.4.0.60.63)
End-Date: 2021-01-08  06:27:21

Start-Date: 2021-01-08  06:27:26
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-modules-5.4.0-60-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-60.67, automatic), linux-image-5.4.0-60-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-60.67, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-60-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-60.67, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.59.62, 5.4.0.60.63)
End-Date: 2021-01-08  06:27:47

Start-Date: 2021-01-08  06:27:52
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox:amd64 (84.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 84.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-08  06:28:00

Start-Date: 2021-01-08  06:28:05
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: tzdata:amd64 (2020d-0ubuntu0.20.04, 2020f-0ubuntu0.20.04)
End-Date: 2021-01-08  06:28:06

Start-Date: 2021-01-08  06:28:10
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-59.65, 5.4.0-60.67)
End-Date: 2021-01-08  06:28:11

Start-Date: 2021-01-08  06:28:16
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libopenjp2-7:amd64 (2.3.1-1ubuntu4, 2.3.1-1ubuntu4.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-08  06:28:16

Start-Date: 2021-01-08  06:28:21
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 (5.4.0.59.62, 5.4.0.60.63)
End-Date: 2021-01-08  06:28:22

Start-Date: 2021-01-08  06:28:26
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox-locale-en:amd64 (84.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 84.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-08  06:28:27

Start-Date: 2021-01-09  06:41:09
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.4.0-59:amd64 (5.4.0-59.65), linux-headers-5.4.0-59-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-59.65)
End-Date: 2021-01-09  06:41:10

Start-Date: 2021-01-09  06:41:15
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-modules-5.4.0-59-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-59.65), linux-image-5.4.0-59-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-59.65), linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-59-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-59.65)
End-Date: 2021-01-09  06:41:19

Start-Date: 2021-01-10  19:24:19
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Requested-By: gamebuster (1000)
Upgrade: libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), xserver-common:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.6, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.6, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1), libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libsignon-qt5-1:amd64 (8.59+17.10.20170606-0ubuntu2, 8.59+17.10.20170606-0ubuntu2.20.04.1), libegl-mesa0:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), update-notifier-common:amd64 (3.192.30, 3.192.30.3), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libglapi-mesa:i386 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), mesa-common-dev:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libsignon-plugins-common1:amd64 (8.59+17.10.20170606-0ubuntu2, 8.59+17.10.20170606-0ubuntu2.20.04.1), xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.6, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1), libxatracker2:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgbm1:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), xserver-xephyr:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.6, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1), libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), xwayland:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.6, 2:1.20.9-2ubuntu1.1~20.04.1), libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), libdrm2:i386 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), libdrm-radeon1:i386 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libdrm-dev:amd64 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1), update-notifier:amd64 (3.192.30, 3.192.30.3), mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libglx-mesa0:amd64 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libglx-mesa0:i386 (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1, 20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libdrm-common:amd64 (2.4.101-2, 2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
End-Date: 2021-01-10  19:24:38

Start-Date: 2021-01-10  19:50:08
Commandline: apt install inxi
Requested-By: gamebuster (1000)
Install: inxi:amd64 (3.0.38-1-0ubuntu1), mesa-utils:amd64 (8.4.0-1build1, automatic), hddtemp:amd64 (0.3-beta15-53, automatic), tree:amd64 (1.8.0-1, automatic)
End-Date: 2021-01-10  19:50:17

Start-Date: 2021-01-10  19:56:42
Commandline: apt purge alsa-base pulseaudio
Requested-By: gamebuster (1000)
Purge: alsa-base:amd64 (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5), ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 (1.450.2), pulseaudio:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8), ubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.450.2), libcanberra-pulse:amd64 (0.30-7ubuntu1), pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8)
End-Date: 2021-01-10  19:56:50

Start-Date: 2021-01-10  19:57:23
Commandline: apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
Requested-By: gamebuster (1000)
Install: alsa-base:amd64 (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5, automatic), ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 (1.450.2, automatic), gnome-session:amd64 (3.36.0-2ubuntu1, automatic), adwaita-icon-theme-full:amd64 (3.36.1-2ubuntu0.20.04.2, automatic), pulseaudio:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8, automatic), fonts-cantarell:amd64 (0.111-2, automatic), ubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.450.2, automatic), ubuntu-gnome-desktop:amd64 (0.87), pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.8, automatic)
End-Date: 2021-01-10  19:57:33

Start-Date: 2021-01-10  20:17:12
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.118'
Install: libnvidia-compute-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-compute-460:i386 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-encode-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-encode-460:i386 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), nvidia-kernel-common-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-gl-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-gl-460:i386 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-fbc1-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-decode-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-decode-460:i386 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.8.0-36-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-cfg1-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), nvidia-utils-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), nvidia-dkms-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-36-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1, automatic), nvidia-compute-utils-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), linux-image-5.8.0-36-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-ifr1-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), nvidia-driver-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-common-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), libnvidia-extra-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic), nvidia-kernel-source-460:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: libnvidia-compute-455:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-compute-455:i386 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-encode-455:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-encode-455:i386 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-kernel-common-455:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-455:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-gl-455:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-gl-455:i386 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-fbc1-455:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-fbc1-455:i386 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-decode-455:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-decode-455:i386 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-cfg1-455:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-utils-455:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-compute-utils-455:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-ifr1-455:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-ifr1-455:i386 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-driver-455:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), linux-modules-nvidia-455-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2, 5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1), libnvidia-common-455:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libnvidia-extra-455:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nvidia-kernel-source-455:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2021-01-10  20:17:51

Start-Date: 2021-01-10  20:18:47
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.118'
Remove: nvidia-kernel-common-455:amd64 (460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2021-01-10  20:18:53

Start-Date: 2021-01-10  20:34:07
Commandline: apt-get purge linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic
Requested-By: gamebuster (1000)
Install: linux-image-unsigned-5.8.0-34-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2, automatic)
Purge: linux-modules-nvidia-455-5.8.0-34-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2), linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2021-01-10  20:34:49

Start-Date: 2021-01-11  06:51:50
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2021-01-11  06:51:56
```

Output of `dpkg -l | grep hw`

```
gamebuster@gamebuster-Area-51-X58:~/Desktop$ dpkg -l | grep hw
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04                               5.4.0.60.63                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel image (dummy transitional package)
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-455-generic-hwe-20.04                  5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1                   amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-455 for the generic flavour (dummy transitional package)
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04                  5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1                   amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-460 for generic-hwe-20.04
ii  lshw
```

Output of `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d` is [here](https://pastebin.com/KuE10Bwk) because the output is too large.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep hw`please and `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: @nobody The information requested has been added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 2 packages

```
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-455-generic-hwe-20.04                  5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1                   amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-455 for the generic flavour (dummy transitional package)
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04                  5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1
```

brought kernel branch 5.8 on your system.

Boot in Kernel 5.4.xxx

and remove any nvidia packages.

```
dpkg -l | egrep linux-'[g|h|i|m]'
```

shows you wich kernel related packages are on your system. Remove any packages that points to kernel branch 5.8.

after that you can install nvidia over ubuntu-drivers

Comment: About an hour before you posted this answer, the system would not boot anymore. I don't have access to the hardware at the moment. I'll see if I can get it to boot via an external usb, and try out your answer when I regain access.